# Why after upgrading to from 12.04 to 14.04 browsers like Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome are not displaying Marathi & Hindi fonts properly?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, firefox, google-chrome, fonts

In last week I upgraded my system from **64-bit 12.04 Ubuntu LTS** to **64-bit 14.04 Ubuntu LTS**.

It also upgraded the browsers **Mozilla Firefox** and **Google Chrome** which were already present on my system.

But after the up-gradation process the **Marathi and Hindi fonts** are not being displayed properly. Especially the words containing joint letters are being displayed as separate letters. Previously it was not happening before upgrade. Look of **English fonts** is also not that much smooth which used to be on **12.04 Ubuntu LTS**.

Can someone please help me out in this issue?

Current Mozilla Firefox Version I'm using is : **45.0**

Current Google Chrome Version I'm using is : **49.0.2623.87 (64-bit)**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading the font cache?

`sudo fc-cache -f -v`

Are the fonts displayed in Fonts settings?

A workaround might be this:

Edit or create file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with following content:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
  Driver  "vesa"
  Option  "UseFBDev"  "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier  "Default Screen"
  Monitor "Configured Monitor"
  Device  "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

[From Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1262089)